# How to get Android webview addjavascriptinterface return class variable | javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

html:

```
`<table>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</table>`
```

---

webview:
`webview?.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[4].innerText);")`

It alwasy return string!

---

How can we use android webview to get table as variable?

```
val table = webview_return_javascript_method
val tr1 = table.tr[0]
```

Comment: The JS interface for Android does not have type safety, so it can return only `String`s from the JS interface. You can convert the data in the `table` to a `JSON` object and return the `String` representation of it to Android which you can then convert back to a `JSONObject`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me! How to get JSON string? I Just know this code: webview?.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[4].innerText);")